# How to put Value Axis(Y) on SSRS 2008

Tags: charts, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a simple line chart that displays running total. It starts from 0 to thousands. I want to move value(Y) axis to the right side of the chart so it is clearer. Alternatively, I would like to put value axis on both sides.

I fail to find that option.

I use SQL Server 2008.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Founded in the end:

1. Right Click on the Data Column
2. Select Axis & Chart area
3. Choose Secondary axis

It is possible to display axis on both side if you put the same data field  twice on the chart.